# Transform an array from one form to another form based on conditions

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array of integers. select each item from array and represent them as sum of x integers

```
array[i] = p1 + p2 + p3 + ... + px that follows below conditions:

a) Each of pi is > 0
b) (x-1) items in pi are even powers of 2.
c) Only 1 item of pi is less than 4.
```

Now the requirement is find the minimum possible value of x for each item in the given input array.

How to solve this problem efficiently.

Comment: Convert the number to base 4. If the last digit is 0, there is no solution. Otherwise, the answer is 1 plus the sum of the base4 digits (not including the last digit).

Comment: @user3386109, thank you. can you please provide details how it solves the problem with an example.

Comment: You have 11 examples in the question that you can try.

Comment: @user3386109, sorry. I am trying to understand `If the last digit is 0, there is no solution. Otherwise, the answer is 1 plus the sum of the base4 digits (not including the last digit).` with the three conditions `(a,b,c)` in my question. I am not able to map them clearly.

Comment: What's 19 in base 4?

Comment: @user3386109, it is 103

Comment: Right. 19 is 16+3. 16 is an even power of 2, and 3 is less than 4. So the answer is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully got the problem statement right. But:

Given a number, it can be represented as a sum of powers of two. i.e.

x = \sum c_i 2^i where c_i \in {0, 1}

You can split your number into 2 sets, the even powers and the odd powers.

Since you know for a fact you cannot reduce the even power set, your potential minimum if it exists must have the number of the even powers + 1. Since you are only allowed one odd number, the minimum, if it exists has the number of even powers + 1.

If you have both i=0 and i=1 there is no solution.

Otherwise you just pick all odd powers of your number and add them together to make the last element which is allowed to not be an even power.

Comment: can you explain in detail please, i am having difficulty in understanding this answer.

Comment: The full solution is there. Since the point of asking this question should be to get better at interview questions I recommend you use this as a guide to understand it on your own.

Read on how numbers on base K are represented as polynomials of powers of K. That should help you understand what binary representations of numbers are in mathematical terms. From then on you can work directly on the polynomial which is easier than thinking about bit patterns.

Comment: `x = \sum c_i 2^i where c_i \in {0, 1}` can you please explain what this statement indicates. as format is missing I am not able to understand this line. Can share an example for this statement also ` Read on how numbers on base K are represented as polynomials of powers of K.`
`

Comment: @learner that is latex formatting. x is your number \sum is the sigma sum notation etc... look up a tex compiler like overleaf and paste it in to see how it is rendered. Most SE sites have formatting but stack overflow explicitly does not have it, which is a pain.

That statement is literally what it says. Numbers in a given base are actually a polynomial. for example in base 10, 145 is  1 * 10^2 + 4 * 10^1 + 5 * 10^0.

I am telling you to learn about that so that you can understand what bit numbers actually are. That will make the question easier.