# modify array by applying the given operations in efficient way

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array of integers, I need to perform update operations on a given range of index positions by just multiplying -1 to the elements at those indices.

**Example:**

```
array = [1,-4,-5,2]
operations = [[1,3],[0,1]]

Result = [-1,-4,5,-2]
```

This is my approach with time complexity as O(m * n).

```
for(int[] out : operations) {
  int x = out[0], y = out[1];
  for(int i=x; i<=y; i++) {
    array[i] *= -1;
  }
}
```

I need an algorithm with less time complexity.

Comment: I assume this is part of the same interview:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701249/transform-an-array-from-one-form-to-another-form-based-on-conditions
Interview questions although annoying are there for a reason, research the issue, write a solution and submit it. They want to see how your solve a problem, not how well you can crowd source.

Comment: If you have written code for this and are having issues with it, please show us your code. If you hae written a solution and want to improve it, this is better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. If you haven't made an attempt yet, please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a difference array to store how many times each element was multiplied by `-1`. This approach works in `O(m + n)`.

```java
int[] array = {1, -4, -5, 2};
int[][] operations = {{1, 3}, {0, 1}};
int[] diff = new int[array.length + 1];
for (var op : operations) {
    ++diff[op[0]];
    --diff[op[1] + 1];
}
for (int i = 1; i < diff.length; i++) diff[i] += diff[i - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    array[i] *= diff[i] % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
// the final result is stored in array
```

Comment: That's still `O(m*n)`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm not sure how you come to that conclusion? There are no nested loops here.